# DateAdd function to add months

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I used this code to add months

```
dtExpiry = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, intDuration, dtStartDate)
```

and I also tried this code,

```
dtExpiry = DateAdd("m", bytDuration, dtMemStartDate)
```

but every time it just adds Days not months. The date format has to be dd/mm/yyyy. I've changed my PC date format to dd/mm/yyyy but still it keeps adding Days instead of Months.

BTW I'm receiving the duration and startDate from the Main calling program which extract these values from a data file thats in CSV format.

Comment: Is it possible to share the values of dtStartDate and the result in dtExpiry?

Comment: so the start date is like 15/02/1990 and then suppose we have to add 6 months it. So the expiry date should be 15/08/1990

Comment: Both lines of code work fine for me if I use your start date and intervals. Could you add the exact input and output? Also, it's VB.NET and not VBA.

Comment: its VB.NET and I've added my question to make it more clear. " I'm receiving the duration and startDate from the Main calling program which extract these values from a data file thats in CSV format."

Comment: Is `dtStartDate` really a DateTime or is it a string (as extracted from that CSV)? Note that a DateTime value doesn't *have* a format. A format applies only when you convert that date to a string (or back).

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks ok, but you may have an incorrect data type.

Try this and see if this works:

```
dtExpiry = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, intDuration, CDate(dtStartDate))
```

If that works then check the data type of `dtStartDate`.

All this can be avoided if you switch [Option Strict On](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143836/i-want-to-turn-vb-net-option-strict-on), as the code won't compile if `dtStartDate` is not of type `DateTime`

Note that you should also be able to do this:

```
dtexpiry = dtStartDate.AddMonths(intDuration)
```

This will fail to compile even with Option Strict Off if `dtStartDate` is not a `DateTime` so could be a safer option.

Answer (score 2):

Use `datetime.tryparse` to convert your string to a date, then use as below?
You can also specify a conversion and specifically tell it what is where in the string (m/d/y)

I.e.:

```
Dim mydate As New Date

mydate = DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault)  

Dim secondDate As New Date
secondDate = mydate.AddMonths(6)
```

Or am I missing your question?